# Bootstrap & Modernizr custom build white screen of death

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modernizr

Adding a Modernizr custom build into my project with Bootstrap prevents anything from rendering.

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tjhillard/gutbd3oo/

HTML:

```
<h3>Hello World???</h3>
```

JS:

Reference jsfiddle above

Comment: Because there's some `hidden` class applied to the html element.

Comment: Where is that coming from and how do I remedy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find `Modernizr.addTest("hidden","hidden"in createElement("a"))` and correct like this:

```
Modernizr.addTest("","hidden"in createElement("a"))
```